# Is it possible to only show the DescriptionField in a custom PXSelector?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm working on a form mod for the Employee Time Activities screen (EP307000). I'm building an additional grid to show all data for a given month. To do that, I need to have a field that allows the user to select a Month/Year combo. I've built the custom PXSelector and gotten all of the data to populate it, but the issue that I'm having is whenever the focus is shifted to that field, the description field is hidden, and only the natural key is shown. For example, if a user selects June 2017, the value stored in the field should be "20170630", but the value shown to the user should be "June-2017".

The "From Week" and "Until Week" PXSelector fields have the functionality I want, but I can't seem to replicate it. This is how "Until Week" is declared:

```
#region TillWeek
public abstract class tillWeek : IBqlField
{
}
[PXDBInt]
[PXWeekSelector2(DescriptionField = typeof(EPWeekRaw.shortDescription))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Until Week", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
public virtual int? TillWeek { set; get; }
#endregion
```

The pictures below show the difference between the fields. The "From Week" field looks different because I removed the "DescriptionField = typeof(EPWeekRaw.shortDescription)" from the PXWeekSelector2.

[image]
[image]

Here's my code for the custom selector:

```
public class MonthYearSelectorAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{

    public MonthYearSelectorAttribute()
        : base(typeof(DateInfoExt.dateInt), new Type[]{ typeof (DateInfoExt.monthName), typeof (DateInfoExt.year)})
    {
        DescriptionField = typeof(DateInfoExt.description);
    }

    public override void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        PX.SM.DateInfo dateInfo = PXSelect<PX.SM.DateInfo, Where<PX.SM.DateInfo.month, Equal<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.month>>, And<PX.SM.DateInfo.year, Equal<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.year>>>>>.Select(this._Graph, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Year);
        int? currentDateInt = dateInfo.DateInt;
        int? pastDateInt = dateInfo.DateInt - 50000;

        foreach(PX.SM.DateInfo result in PXSelectGroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo, Where<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt, LessEqual<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.year>>, And<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt, GreaterEqual<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt>>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo.month, GroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo.year>>>, OrderBy<Asc<PX.SM.DateInfo.year, Asc<PX.SM.DateInfo.month>>>>.Select(this._Graph, currentDateInt, pastDateInt))
        {
            DateInfoExt ext = new DateInfoExt();
            ext.Year = result.Year;
            ext.MonthName = result.MonthName;
            ext.DateInt = result.DateInt;
            ext.Description = result.MonthName + "-" + result.Year.ToString();
            yield return ext;
        }
    }
}
public class DateInfoExt : IBqlTable
{
    public DateInfoExt()
    {
    }
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class description : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "MonthYear", IsReadOnly = true)]
    public virtual string MonthYear { get; set; }
    public abstract class monthYear : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Month Name", IsReadOnly = true)]
    public virtual string MonthName { get; set; }
    public abstract class monthName : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Year", IsReadOnly = true)]
    public virtual int? Year { get; set; }
    public abstract class year : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date (Integer)", IsReadOnly = true, Visible = false)]
    public virtual int? DateInt { get; set; }
    public abstract class dateInt : IBqlField
    {
    }
}
public class PMTimeActivityFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.EP.EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter>
{

    public abstract class month : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [MonthYearSelector]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Month", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    public virtual int Month
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt #1:** Can this be the **DisplayMode** property set to ***Text*** missing on your PXSelector control in Aspx?

```
<px:PXSelector runat="server" DataField="Month" ID="edMonth" ... DisplayMode="Text"/>
```

**Attempt #2:** Below is the only achievable result supported by the framework - the *Year-Month* combination followed by the *MonthName Year* description within parentheses.:
[image]

It won't be possible to show value from one field inside the Month selector and order records within the drop-down grid by some other field - such behavior is simply not supported by the framework.

To get the result above, you should set Visible to false for the PXUIFieldAttribute used on DateInfoExt Description field:

```
public class DateInfoExt : IBqlTable
{
    ...
    public abstract class description : IBqlField { }
    [PXString()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description", Visible = false)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

and slightly change how Description field of the DateInfoExt DAC gets populated with values within the delagate:

```
foreach (PX.SM.DateInfo result in PXSelectGroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo, 
    Where<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt, LessEqual<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.year>>, 
        And<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt, GreaterEqual<Required<PX.SM.DateInfo.dateInt>>>>, 
    Aggregate<GroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo.month, GroupBy<PX.SM.DateInfo.year>>>, 
    OrderBy<Asc<PX.SM.DateInfo.year, Asc<PX.SM.DateInfo.month>>>>.Select(this._Graph, currentDateInt, pastDateInt))
{
    DateInfoExt ext = new DateInfoExt();
    ext.DateInt = result.DateInt;
    ext.Year = result.Year;
    ext.MonthName = result.MonthName;
    ext.Description = string.Format("{0}-{1} ({2} {0})", result.Year, result.Month, result.MonthName);
    yield return ext;
}
```

This is how I declared **Month** selector in Aspx:

```
<px:PXSelector runat="server" DataField="Month" ID="edMonth" CommitChanges="True" TextMode="Search" ValueField="DateInt" DisplayMode="Text"/>
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but now it's ordering by the description instead of the dateInt field.

Comment: Thanks! @RuslanDev